# Is there a standard code in that can format phone numbers into some "standard format"

Tags: string

For example, say we know that the default area code is 21, and the country code is 62

```
123456789 -> 6221123456789
021123456789 -> 6221123456789
022123456789 -> 6222123456789
6222123456789 -> 6222123456789
(62)21 123456789 -> 6221123456789
```

Basically this seems simple. However, I wonder if there is a rule for phone number.

For example, is first 2 digit always country code if the length of phone number is 10?

What sort of formatting that IOS uses anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat#rmphoneformat

Some posts somewhere on some questions mention this. This is what I will use.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly different countries have different standards and even countries have different standards they use which you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers#United_Kingdom).

YOu could either target different counties with different rules or just pick a format that you think makes sense, or allow the user to change the format.

Answer (score 1):

Use this
https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS

```
NBPhoneNumberUtil *phoneUtil = [NBPhoneNumberUtil sharedInstance];

NSError *aError = nil;
NBPhoneNumber *myNumber1 = [phoneUtil parse:@"6766077303" defaultRegion:@"AT" error:&aError];
if (aError == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"isValidPhoneNumber ? [%@]", [phoneUtil isValidNumber:myNumber1] ? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"E164          : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber1 numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatE164]);
    NSLog(@"INTERNATIONAL : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber1 numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatINTERNATIONAL]);
    NSLog(@"NATIONAL      : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber1 numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatNATIONAL]);
    NSLog(@"RFC3966       : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber1 numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatRFC3966]);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", [aError localizedDescription]);
}
```